# Compile beyond pre-processor stage but before assembly stage

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, macros, c-preprocessor

Imagine I have a set of macros in a program (macrotest.c) like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n1 75
#define n2 90
#define mac(x,y) ((x > y) ? (12) : (15))

int main(){

   printf("%d",mac(n1,n2));
   exit(0);
}
```

When you compile down to assembly (EM64T), you get the following:

**gcc -S -o macrotest.asm macrotest.c**

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    $15, %esi   <------ This
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %edi
    call    exit
    .cfi_endproc
```

You can see that it immediately converts the mac(n1,n2) to 15.
However, when you compile to the pre-processor stage, it merely expands out the macros:

**gcc -E -o macrotest.prp macrotest.c**

```
int main(){

   printf("%d",((75 > 90) ? (12) : (15)));
   exit(0);
}
```

Is there some way I can further break down the **C** code without going into assembly?

Comment: I don't think you can go much deeper than this because optimizations are applied while compiling so that 15 would have come from first parsing the expression and then doing in place evaluation.

Comment: @JesusRamos Surely there is some tool out there that can do what I'm asking for.

Comment: Well the compiler would do it but the thing is that it would not really produce output such as this (in your case just replace the whole thing with 15) because some of those things are specific and would require code reordering which might make code unreadable almost.

Comment: @JesusRamos You may be right. Still I'm going to sit on this question for some time, it's kind of important.

Comment: I've seen utilities that go from assembly to TCG and back but never something that does inline optimizations directly into the code. It would be interesting if such a tool did exist though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the option `-fdump-tree-all` and see if that tells you what you need?

This dumps the internal representation of the compiler. It does not use C code (you couldn't take it and compile it), but it does look a bit like C. If you want to understand it more, read up on 'Single Static Assignment' (SSA).

If you want to take this even further towards assembler, then add `-fdump-rtl-all`. For the second half of the process GCC switches from SSA form (in which the compiler attempts to optimize the program), and uses what it calls "Register Transfer Language". The purpose of this phase is to optimize the low-level machine instruction usage. This is even harder to understand. Try reading the GCC internals manual.